# Calculation function not "recognizing" a change

Tags: jquery

First of all I've looked everywhere for an answer but since I'm a noob, I suspect I just don't know what to google.

I have multiple input fields, where the two last rows inherit the inputs of the top ones.

I haven't inherited the "total" value because it has no need to be inherited.

What I want the function to recognize is the inherited values on the bottom rows as "changes" and do the summation function to calculate what the total on those rows will be. Since you'll be able to do further calculations it would be nice to just have it in the one function.

Question:
What I need to know is how I make the function recognize the inherited values without having to change it again, or put it on blur because I leave the field. I want it to be automatic.

Solution 1:
Inherit the top "total" to then change the bottom rows and get a new total if needed.

Solution 2: 
Make the function recognize the "set value" is a change and do calculations after that.

Both solutions stem from the problem of not manually putting in a value in the input and therefore not getting a calculation.

http://jsfiddle.net/zcu2wqm4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// FUNCTION 5 - copy data to other Karmdimension fields

    $(".left").keyup(function () {
        $(".left2").val(this.value);
    });

    $(".right").keyup(function () {
        $(".right2").val(this.value);
    });

// END FUNCTION

// FUNCTION 6 - CALCULATION FUNCTION summary from price-fields

    $('input[name=left]').keyup(function() {  
        updateTotal();
    });

    $('input[name=right]').keyup(function() {  
        updateTotal();
    });

    var updateTotal = function () {

        var input1 = parseInt($('input[name=left]').val());
        var input2 = parseInt($('input[name=right]').val());

        if (isNaN(input1) || isNaN(input2)) {

            $('input[name=sum]').val('Both inputs must be numbers');

        } 

        else {    

        $('input[name=sum]').val(input1 + input2);

        }
    };


    // FIELD B PRICE SUMMARY


    $('input[name=left2]').keyup(function() {  
        updateTotal2();
    });

    $('input[name=right2]').keyup(function() {  
        updateTotal2();
    });

    var updateTotal2 = function () {

        var input1 = parseInt($('input[name=left2]').val());
        var input2 = parseInt($('input[name=right2]').val());

        if (isNaN(input1) || isNaN(input2)) {

            $('input[name=sum2]').val('Both inputs must be numbers');

        } 

        else {    

        $('input[name=sum2]').val(input1 + input2);

        }
    };


    // FIELD C PRICE SUMMARY


    $('input[name=left3]').keyup(function() {  
        updateTotal3();
    });

    $('input[name=right3]').keyup(function() {  
        updateTotal3();
    });

    var updateTotal3 = function () {

        var input1 = parseInt($('input[name=left3]').val());
        var input2 = parseInt($('input[name=right3]').val());

        if (isNaN(input1) || isNaN(input2)) {

            $('input[name=sum3]').val('Both inputs must be numbers');

        } 

        else {    

        $('input[name=sum3]').val(input1 + input2);

        }
    };

// END FUNCTION

});
```

Comment: Note that `keyup` isn't fired when the value is changed by other means, e.g. by pressing the up/down buttons, or using the mouse scroll wheel.

Comment: Duly noted! I was aware of it and thought I had taken it into consideration, but I just noticed I hadn't fixed that in the end code. Thank you! (Although keyup looks way more cool! Heh...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery *change* event, in combination with an *or* selector and a slight tweak to your html to handle all of these activities in one function call:

**Example HMTL:**

```
<input type="number" name="left1" class="left" min="0" />
<input type="number" name="right1" class="right" min="0"/>
<input type="number" name="sum1" class="total" disabled />

<br />

<input type="number" class="left" name="left2" min="0" />
<input type="number" class="right" name="right2" min="0" />
<input type="number" class="total" name="sum2" disabled />


<!-- snip .. -->
```

In the above example, the classes have been changed to be the same for each input of a similar type (right, left, total) while keeping the names different. This is so we can use jQuery's *or* selector, and bind it to the `on` event like this:

```
$('.left, .right').on('change', function(){ /* snip... */});
```

If either an element with the class `left` or the class `right` value changes, an event will fire. You're then able to isolate what specific element was *changed* with `this`, and use trivial logic / code to achieve your desired behavior:

```
var itemClass = $(this).attr('class'); //<-- gives you the elements class (left or right)
```

**Example Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // for later use..
  var right = 0,
    left = 0,
    total = 0;

  $(".left, .right").on('change', function() {

    // get the class, matching elems and value
    var itemClass = $(this).attr('class'),
      elems = $('.' + itemClass),
      itemVal = $(this).val();
    
    
    if (itemClass == 'right') {
      right = itemVal;
    } else {
      left = itemVal;
    }

    // set all like inputs to the same value
    elems.val(itemVal);

    // recalculate the total:
    total = parseInt(right) + parseInt(left);
    $('.total').val(total);

  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- -->
<form>
  <input type="number" name="left1" class="left" min="0" />
  <input type="number" name="right1" class="right" min="0" />
  <input type="number" name="sum1" class="total" disabled />

  <br />

  <input type="number" class="left" name="left2" min="0" />
  <input type="number" class="right" name="right2" min="0" />
  <input type="number" class="total" name="sum2" disabled />

  <br />

  <input type="number" class="left" name="left3" min="0" />
  <input type="number" class="right" name="right3" min="0" />
  <input type="number" class="total" name="sum3" disabled />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I understand why your solution could help a lot of people, so I'm marking it as correct. 

However what I intended to do was this:

http://jsfiddle.net/zcu2wqm4/26/

Which is probably a very erratical and nonwanted behavior in most cases.